# I am not able to find windows phone emulators in VS 2015 Latest community version

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-8-emulator

I'm not able to see any of emulator in VS 2015  for windows phone. My system has all requirements to run an emulator. previously I was able to debug on emulator. After uninstalling and reinstalling VS2013 to VS 2015 (latest)I'm unable to get emulator list and i'm getting error

> "There were deployment error" and error list shows " Error 1
>   Exception from HRESULT: 0x89721500".

Please help me to solve this problem as I'm unable to test my window phone apps on my system.

Answer (score 0):

right click your project, and see if there's a menu item "Add Windows 8.1".  That worked for me, even though it was a Windows Phone 8.1 project.  Huh!